# Login loop Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS again

Tags: 14.04, login

Today i've faced with loggin loop on my Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS again. I've started with most popular scenarios to fix but everything fails. All articles on the first 4-5 pages of google search are read but no success.

For now i can login to Guest, to tty with my user, to my new user using GUI, but my old user via GUI is unreachable.

Could you please point me somewhere how i can fix it??

Answer (score 0):

If you modified or deleted a config file in your home folder. You could do:

backup old config files: `mkdir /home/(oldUser)/hidden_config && cp /home/(oldUser)/.?* /home/(oldUser)/hidden_config`

copy config files from new user:
 `cp /home/(newUser)/.?* /home/(olduser)/`

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something I dealt with a while back.  Try logging into a TTY with administrative credentials, then entering the following commands:

`sudo mv ~/.Xauthority ~/.Xauthority.backup`

`sudo service lightdm restart`

Comment: this one was the first i've tried with no luck.